# how can fix the error Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in Can"t Insert in to database

Tags: php, mysqli

I cant get `insert into` database and `bind_param` to work.

```
  $query="INSERT INTO user (UserName,email,Password) VALUES ('?','?','?')";
    $inst=$this->db->prepare($query);
    $inst->bind_param("sss",$username,$email,$password);
    if(!$inst) {
        echo "Query Prep Failed: %s\n", $conn->error;
        exit;
    }
    $username="";
    $email="";
    $password="";
    $inst->execute();
```

Comment: The prepare step failed, so you have to check `$this->db->error`.

Comment: Please describe Am not Get it

Comment: Write ? instead of '?'

Comment: prepare should be used with object of MySqli. Just try instead of `this->db->` to `SomeMySqliObject` and you are not required to do '?' else you can just use ?

Comment: This can be the problem, but if $this->db contains an object of mysqli it still should work...

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you use a instance of mysqli:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "database");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO user (UserName, email, Password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $username, $email, $password);
$stmt->execute();
```